# Role of Swift 3 lazy var with no getter

Tags: swift

I am wondering the meaning of lazy keyword when I am not working with a getter or setter. Look at this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    lazy var toto = 5
}
```

The compiler accepts the lazy keyword but I do not know why. Lazy means the value will me calculated only when reading. But there is no need to compute anything for an integer value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lazy` means that the initial value of *stored property* is evaluated and assigned on the first access (so this is actually unrelated to getters
or setters which are used with *computed* properties).

```
lazy var toto = ... some expression evaluating to an `Int` ...
```

defines a lazy `Int` property.

`lazy` can be used to delay the evaluation of the initial value
until the property is needed, e.g. if that evaluation is
"expensive" or has side effects.

But from the language/compiler point of view, the initial value on the right-hand side
 can be an arbitrary expression.
 It does not matter if  it is a constant or a "complicated" expression involving function calls.

```
lazy var a = 5 // A constant
lazy var b = someFunctionReturningAnInt() // Function call
lazy var c = { _ -> Int in
               return 42
             }()               // Immediately evaluated closure
```

are all valid definitions. There is no advantage of using `lazy` with a constant initial value, but it is valid Swift.

Answer (score 2):

You should only use lazy to initialize a new class variable.
The [official Swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) gives a very good example, summary as below:

```
 class DataImporter {
    init() {
      //importing data, non-trivial task
    }
  }

  class DataManager {
    lazy var dataImporter = DataImporter()

    init() {
      //here, dataImporter is not yet created because it is lazy to move its ass~
  }


 let manager = DataManager() // manager.dataImporter is NOT created yet
 manager.dataImporter //ONLY now it is created
```

Comment: what do you mean by class variable ? Can you give me an example in swift ?